# Propogating Events to Child Components in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to send events down to my React child.

I feel like this is kind of an easy thing to do, so maybe i just have a mental block, and there is something obvious that is staring me in the face.

Anyway, I have a little Test app which illustrates the problem:

```
export class Test extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {};
    }

    render() {
        let {buttonClicked, textFieldChanged} = this.state
        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={()=>this.handleClick()}>
                    Click
                </button>
                <input type={"text"} onChange={()=>this.handleTextChange()}/>
                <Inner buttonClicked={buttonClicked} textFieldChanged={textFieldChanged}/>
            </div>
        );
    }

    handleClick(e) {
        this.setState({ buttonClicked: true })
    }

    handleTextChange(e) {
        this.setState({textFieldChanged:true})
    }
}


class Inner extends React.Component {
    render() {
        let {buttonClicked, textFieldChanged} = this.props;
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <div>Clicked : {buttonClicked ? "CLICKED!" : " "}</div>
                <div>Text input : {textFieldChanged ? "TYPED!" : " "}</div>
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}
```

A button and a textfield live in the parent. Both these widgets can fire off events and change the child component.

This is simply achieved by passing a state value as a property down to the child. Very easy stuff.

However I would like an either/or situation. When I click the button this removes the text event, and vice versa. Ie. I do not want to see a situation like this :

[image]

Now there is a very obvious way to fix this by changing the state value to "false" of the *other* value.

```
handleClick(e) {
    this.setState({ buttonClicked: true, textFieldChanged: false })
}

handleTextChange(e) {
    this.setState({textFieldChanged:true, buttonClicked: false})
}
```

Is there any OTHER way of doing this?

The problem is that I have LOTS and LOTS of even handlers in my component and I don't want to negate the other state properties of the other values.

Comment: Can't you just assume that changed is false if clicked is true and clicked is false when changed is true? This way you can get rid of either clicked or changed.

Answer (score 2):

if i understood you correctly just one function will help - pass the attribute name into it

```
handleClick(propName) {
    this.setState({ 
        ...this.state,
        [propName]: !this.state[propName]
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create property lastEventType in parent component state , whenever you click or type - update it. And pass only this property to Inner component